# AS3 tracking and using coordinates of a rotated object

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, rotatetransform

How does one track and use the coordinates of an object that is rotated on initialization?

Let's say I have a sword that is put on the stage in Main init(); and rotated (adjusted) so that it would look ok together with the character perspective. In another class however, I am making the sword rotate some more on a keypress timer event so to create a 'swing' animation.

All this is done through flashdevelop. I only used CS6 to create the symbols. And as this 'swing' is happening, I want to add another symbol onto the tip of the sword which is a collision point object. It's being added to the stage when the swing starts and removed after every swing. I want this object to follow the very tip of the sword, yet it seems like I can only achieve that it follows the coordinates of the original sword object, as if I hadn't initially modified the rotation of the said sword. I tried to implement GlobalToLocal() and LocalToGlobal() methods, but I don't think I fully understand what is happening with that.

I hope I'm being clear enough of what I'm trying to do. Thank you. This is the relevant code in question. The code is as was before I tried the two mentioned methods and the issue currently is exactly as described before that. Do I want any of those methods or am I just doing something else wrong?

**Main initialization:**

```
sword = new Sword();

sword.x = 53;
sword.y = 90;
addChild(sword);
sword.rotationZ = -150;
sword.rotationY = 25;
sword.rotationX = -15;

Coll_Point = new coll_point();
```

**The class that deals with the swing has a method like this:**

```
private function SwingTime(event:Event):void
{
    Main.Coll_Point.x = Main.sword.x + Main.sword.width;
    Main.Coll_Point.y = Main.sword.y + Main.sword.height;
    Main.MazeNr1.addChild(Main.Coll_Point);

    if (Main.sword.rotationZ > -330)
    Main.sword.rotationZ -= 20;

    if (Main.sword.rotationX < 15)
    Main.sword.rotationX += 10;

    if ((Main.sword.rotationZ == -330) && (Main.sword.rotationX == 15))
    {
        SwingTimer.stop();
        SwingBckTimer.start();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
A more holistic version of the code:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
    public static var from_point:Point = null;
    public static var to_point:Point = new Point();
    public function Main():void
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    // Puts everything on the stage here.
    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        PlayerInst = new Dorf();
        PlayerInst.x = 45;
        PlayerInst.y = 51;
        addChild(PlayerInst);

        sword = new Sword();
        sword.x = 53;
        sword.y = 90;
        sword.rotationZ = -150;
        sword.rotationY = 25;
        sword.rotationX = -15;
        from_point = new Point (Main.sword.width, Main.sword.height);
        to_point = sword.localToGlobal(from_point);
        addChild(sword);
        swordBD = new BitmapData(32, 32, true, 0x0000000000);
        swordBD.draw(sword);

        Coll_Point = new coll_point();
        Coll_PointBD = new BitmapData(2, 2, true, 0x0000000000);
        Coll_PointBD.draw(Coll_Point);
    }
}
```

This is how the Main looks like and literally every single object instantiation is added onto the stage this way. Including collision points, background, characters, gradient fills of line of sight radius, etc. And the relevant symbol class goes somewhat like this:

```
public class Creature extends MovieClip 
{
    protected var Swing:Boolean;
    private var SwingTimer:Timer = new Timer (5, 0);
    private var SwingBckTimer:Timer = new Timer (150, 1);
// Constructor.
    public function Creature()
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    // Initializer.
    private function init(event:Event = null):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        SwingTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, SwingTime);
        SwingBckTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, SwingBack);
    }
private function SwingAction():void
    {
        if (Swing == true)
        {
            SwingTimer.start();
        }
    }

    private function SwingTime(event:Event):void
    {
        Main.Coll_Point.x = Main.sword.localToGlobal(Main.from_point).x;
        Main.Coll_Point.y = Main.sword.localToGlobal(Main.from_point).y;
        Main.sword.addChild(Main.Coll_Point);
        trace(Main.Coll_Point.x);
        trace(Main.Coll_Point.y);

        if (Main.sword.rotationZ > -330)
        Main.sword.rotationZ -= 20;

        if (Main.sword.rotationX < 15)
        Main.sword.rotationX += 10;

        if ((Main.sword.rotationZ == -330) && (Main.sword.rotationX == 15))
        {
            SwingTimer.stop();
            SwingBckTimer.start();
        }
    }

    private function SwingBack(event:Event):void
    {
        Main.sword.rotationZ = -150;
        Main.sword.rotationX = -15;
        //Main.MazeNr1.removeChild(Main.Coll_Point);
    }
```

There is also a rather long update(); function that animates and moves every single object that needs moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be in

```
    Main.Coll_Point.x = Main.sword.x + Main.sword.width;
    Main.Coll_Point.y = Main.sword.y + Main.sword.height;
```

Coll_Point expects global coordinates.

The parts `+ Main.sword.width` and `+ Main.sword.height` only work as expected if the sword is not rotated so that height is aligned with the y-axis and width with the x-axis.

You should use [localToGlobal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) on the position that is local to `Main.sword` (
`Main.sword.width, Main.sword.height`) to get the global position that represents the swords rotated tip before you add it as a child.

**There are two ways you can approach this (you seem to have somewhat combined both). You can either**

- Add the Coll_Point as a child to something above the sword in hierarchy (Stage, MazeNr1, ...) and update the position manually every timer callback. You would have to recalculate the position everytime, so take the `localToGlobal()` from init to your timer function. It won't update if it doesn't get called.

For that you should have this kind of code in the timer callback:

```
var local:Point = new Point(Main.sword.width, Main.sword.height);
var global:Point = Main.sword.localToGlobal(local);
Main.Coll_Point.x = global.x;
Main.Coll_Point.y = global.y;
```

- Add the point as a child to the sword. This might be a better approach as then the position will be updated automatically. What I did not remember before was that you then give the coordinates in "local" form, so do not use `localToGlobal()`

Run this once where you create the `Collision_Point`:

```
Coll_Point.x = <your x offset>;
Coll_Point.y = <your y offset>;
Main.sword.attachChild(Coll_Point);
```

Instead of sword `height` and `width` you might want to try something like `-height` and `width/2`.

Here is a quick (and not the prettiest) picture to demonstrate the problem. Local space is rotated with the object:

[image]

Comment: Ok. Do you mean use the LocalToGlobal() in the main initialization before I add the sword onto the stage?

Comment: @Juris Zebnickis Instead of adding the width and height to the (global) x and y on the two lines above, give the (local) off set to LocalToGlobal() and you'll get a pair of X and Y coordinates. Wait a sec, I'll try writing an example. As I said on the other question, my AS3 is a bit rusty :)

Comment: So I tried to do that. What am I not getting? Added these in Main: `public static var from_point:Point = null;
  public static var to_point:Point = new Point();`
`from_point = new Point (Main.sword.x + Main.sword.width, Main.sword.y + Main.sword.height);
   to_point = sword.localToGlobal(from_point);`
and these in the swing method:
`Main.Coll_Point.x = Main.to_point.x;
   Main.Coll_Point.y = Main.to_point.y;
   Main.MazeNr1.addChild(Main.Coll_Point);`

Comment: If yours is rusty.. I should just kill myself. I've been stumped with this single problem for all day today.

Comment: @JurisZebnickis You should not need the sword.x and sword.y offsets in local space. Local space is "inside" the sword object after all. Try my edit out.

Comment: I did. Now I'm tracing the Coll_Point x and y coordinates and it's always returning 256 and 412 throughout the swing motion method. So the point isn't moving anymore either. The code is the same as above, I just deleted the parts you said I wouldn't need. Can I get you a beer?

Comment: @JurisZebnickis Edit: removed, I don't think it was the case... Try tracing what `Main.sword.localToGlobal(local)` returns?

Comment: My MazeNr1 is an instantiation of my base level class so I treat it as the stage. However I did change that about as well. I tried having just addChild and Main.sword.addChild and this.addChild (Cause the class dealing with the swing method is my character object class), but nothing changes. It keeps returning the same now seemingly static values of Coll_Point coords.

Comment: Wait. The trace is returning a static value because I'm using widht and height for the LocalToGlobal method argument, not the coordinates. So of course it's not changing. Why am I doing this? Also the local trace returns (x=34, y=45)
(x=22, y=50)
(x=12, y=62)
(x=7, y=80)
(x=6, y=95)
(x=11, y=109)
(x=21, y=121)
(x=34, y=129)
(x=49, y=132)
which seem legit and usable values.

Comment: @JurisZebnickis the width and height tell localToGlobal a part within the object that you want, which is then rotated along the object. That is the output of the localToGlobal function / values of the global variable? If so everything should be working that far

Comment: I used the = Main.sword.localToGlobal(Main.from_point). line to 'hard assign' the Coll_Point coordinate values and it seems to be almost working. Except the point seems to be twice the distance away from the sword origin. As if I was adding double the x and y distance.

Comment: @JurisZebnickis Hmm. Hard to say what's wrong without seeing the code (the meaningful part) as a whole. You might want to add an updated version to the Q so it would be easier to read.

Comment: I think this would work **only** if you position your registration point very carefully within the sword itself. You haven't specified where's that registration point and how the rotation will work. I advise you to do a simple test and see how this goes, as it's pretty obvious that the X is placed in the center of the sword on the x axis, and the code you provide won't work **if** the registration point of the sword is not properly set.

Comment: I made a quick test and I totally don't get how this can work. Adding width and height means that the registration point **must** be bottom left and still the collision point would go top right..

Comment: @AndreyPopov Well it is symbol/sprite dependant. I just took the values he originally used (which might/might not have been the right). I tried a small test too and it worked fine after I adjusted the local offsets to my liking.

Comment: @JurisZebnickis Updated A. You don't need to get me anything, get your code to work :)

Comment: Well if you need to adjust it via code and calculate localToGlobal on each frame, then I think this is a huge overload that is not needed. Sorry to say that.. :

Comment: @AndreyPopov Should not be necessary. That seemed to be part of his original code where I only gave a fix for the positioning part. Now I split my A to two and added a better solution. (Tested to work)

Comment: Child of the sword?! This becomes pretty weird to me, I'm ending this discussion.

Comment: Yo yo, don't go. I went to sleep last night. =/ And what concerns the sword and its origin, I created it so that on  the non-modified, original sword image the tip is on the bottom right, because I needed the origin point (0, 0) to be the handle so that I can 'swing' it realistically if you know what I mean. I hope this provides some more insight.

Comment: @JurisZebnickis Did you try the new stuff I edited to my answer?

Comment: Yes. The first solution seems to be working exactly as I need except the arc that the collision point travels seems to be a lot wider (further away from the tip, but still on the trajectory of the sword). Don't know why that is. And I suppose I'll deal with adding and removing the collision point between the swings by just positioning it somewhere far away and outside from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can imagine to help you with this problem is to have your collision object have the same registration point as the sword. What I mean is that the orientation points should match, and the collision graphic should be moved **inside** of the sprite so that it matches the position of the top of the sword.

This way you can put the collision object at the very same location of the sword and apply the very same rotation. This way it will move along with the top of the sword and still have hitTest working properly.

I cannot imagine any other way to figure this out as any code will get bounds and positions. But the real thing that matters is the registration point and the top of the sword, which is a graphic thing and cannot be dealt with coding.

I hope you can imagine what I mean - if now, just say and I will provide an image for you :)

Comment: Would it not work if when setting the initial position for the point he used `localToGlobal()` to get the tip of the sword, then add it as a child so they rotated together?

Comment: The tip of the sword it not the width/height of that sword. If the registration point is at bottom/center (for proper rotation), then the tip of the sword it at Point(0, -sword.height)..